# You are running version v8.9.3 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My current angular version is '^7.1.4' and I want to continue with same version. but while doing ng serve I am getting below error.

You are running version v8.9.3 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater.

Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js.

Node version   : v8.9.3
NPM Version  : 6.4.1

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you upgrade angular/cli? What's the version number in package.json? Did you recently initiate an Angular 8 project?

Comment: https://update.angular.io/ - Follow this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like your global CLI version got upgraded to 8. To downgrade to 7 try this:

```
 ng --version
 npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
 npm cache clean --force

 npm install -g @angular/cli@7.1.4
 ng --version
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you might have upgraded your angular/cli to latest, downgrade it to version 7.1.4. Run these commands -

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force    
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.1.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nvm for a different angular project you can switch your node version as your requirement, here I attach a link to install nvm.
https://itnext.io/nvm-the-easiest-way-to-switch-node-js-environments-on-your-machine-in-a-flash-17babb7d5f1b

Comment: I'm using nvm and have this exact problem.  "ng -v" always shows the wrong version of node.js being used, even though I'm using nvm, and I've run "nvm use 10.16.0" to use v10.16 of node.js.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue you have to use that version of **NodeJS** which is compatible or supported by the **Angular CLI**.

You can take reference through this link [Angular CLI, Angular, and Node.js compatibility matrix.](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3) to understand the version compatibility and downgrade or upgrade the NodeJs version accordingly.

To upgrade or downgrade the **NodeJS** Version you can use **NVM**.

Always try to use the **LTS version of NodeJS** while working with the Angular CLI because there might be a case in which the **Angular CLI** version does not support the version of **NodeJs** That's why it is recommended to use the **LTS version of NodeJS**.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.